# Why can't I access req.user in passport.use()?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm writing a small e-commerce app with third-party login via Google using a PostgreSQL database. This is my Google Strategy configuration:

```js
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth").OAuth2Strategy;
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: `${process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? [production URL] : "http://localhost:8000"}/api/auth/login/google/callback`,
    passReqToCallback: true,
    scope: ["email", "profile"]
}, db.third.login));
```

And this is `db.third.login` below, which is working perfectly with both newly registered and existing users who authenticated themselves via Google. Alongside authenticating the user, it also passes information that ultimately forces a newly registered user to set a phone number and password in the client before they can use the app.

```js
const login = async(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    // Get request IP address
    const ip = requestIP.getClientIp(req);

    // Generate login attempt ID
    const attemptId = idGen(15);

    try { // Get federated credentials
        let result = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM federated_credentials WHERE id = $1 AND provider = $2", [profile.id, profile.provider]);

        // Create user account if credentials don't exist
        if (result.rows.length === 0) {
            // Send error if email already exists in database
            result = await pool.query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = $1", [profile.emails[0].value]);
            if (result.rows.length > 0) return done({ status: 409, message: "Error: A user with the provided email already exists." });

            // Generate user ID and cart ID
            const userId = idGen(7);
            const cartId = idGen(7);

            // Generate password hash
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(17);
            const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(process.env.GENERIC_PASSWORD, salt);

            // Add user to database
            let text = `INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, phone, email, password, created_at) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, to_timestamp(${Date.now()} / 1000)) RETURNING id`;
            let values = [userId, profile.name.givenName, profile.name.familyName, "254700000000", profile.emails[0].value, passwordHash];
            result = await pool.query(text, values);

            // Add user cart to database
            result = await pool.query("INSERT INTO carts (id, user_id) VALUES ($1, $2)", [cartId, userId]);

            // Add federated credentials to database
            result = await pool.query("INSERT INTO federated_credentials (id, provider, user_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", [profile.id, profile.provider, userId]);

            // Add user details to be confirmed to session
            const federatedCredentials = { id: profile.id, provider: profile.provider, confirm: true };
            return done(null, { id: userId, email: profile.emails[0].value, role: "customer", cartId: cartId, federatedCredentials });
        }

        // Save federated credentials details
        const federatedCredentials = { id: result.rows[0].id, provider: result.rows[0].provider, confirm: !result.rows[0].confirmed };

        // Get user details
        result = await pool.query("SELECT users.id AS id, users.email AS email, users.password AS password, users.role AS role, carts.id AS cart_id FROM users JOIN carts ON carts.user_id = users.id WHERE email = $1", [profile.emails[0].value]);

        // Log login attempt
        await loginAttempt(attemptId, ip, profile.emails[0].value, "google", true);

        // Add user to session
        return done(null, { id: result.rows[0].id, email: result.rows[0].email, role: result.rows[0].role, cartId: result.rows[0].cart_id, federatedCredentials });
    } catch (err) {
        return done({ status: 500, message: "An unknown error occurred. Kindly try again." });
    }
}
```

I'd now like to add functionality that allows existing users (who registered otherwise) to link their Google accounts, but my problem is that `req.user` is apparently not accessible in `passport.use()` (console logs show that it is `undefined` even after I've logged in). How can I access information on the current user in the session in `passport.use()` to make this happen? (Or is there another solution altogether?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some digging on the [Passport repository on GitHub](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) and found a user who reported setting the `sameSite` property in the `express-session` `cookie` object to `"lax"` as a working solution, and it worked for me as well. You can [read the comment here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/803#issuecomment-912669849).

```js
const session = require("express-session");
app.use(session({
    ... // other session options
    cookie: {
        ... // other cookie options
        sameSite: "lax" 
    }
}));
```

Hopefully Mr. Jared Hanson can provide an update on why this is the case soon (as well as a fix that allows unconditional access to `req.user` from `passport.use()`).